# RecyclerView scrolls to the top when I open another activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-lifecycle

I have a RecyclerView in my Fragment. When I open another activity, then hit back and go to the initial activity/fragment, the RecyclerView is now scrolled to the top of the list.

I'm initiating my RecyclerView inside of onCreate method, and when I navigate to another activity and come back, only onStop (and the once after obviously) get called.

I even tried saving the state of the LinearLayout manager

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    rcerecylerViewState  = myRecyclerView.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState()
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    if(rcerecylerViewState != null){
        myRecyclerView.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(newsFeedViewModel.rcerecylerViewState)
    }
}
```

I dont want to clutter this post by including my whole layout and fragment file. Please let me know which part of the code I should include to further clarify.

Comment: Did you use finish() when you go to the next activity? Unfortunately you need to post code that's relevant to your question. Not what you added in your question.

Answer (score 0):

No need to do anything in `onStart`.

Move your `onStart` code into your `onCreate`.

Pseudocode looks like this.

```
if (recyclerview != null) 
    // restoredata
else 
    // initial set up.
```